# I can't seem to import BlockDecoder into my typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, hyperledger-fabric

This is my code
although the import is on the second line of the code it doesn't work
so I don't know what to do next

```js
import { Gateway, Wallets } from 'fabric-network';
import { BlockDecoder } from 'fabric-common';
import * as path from 'path';
    import * as fs from 'fs';
    
    async function main() {
        try {
            // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
            const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'Org1Wallet');
            const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
            console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
    
            // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
            const gateway = new Gateway();
            const connectionProfilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..',
                'connection.json');
            const connectionProfile: any =
                JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(connectionProfilePath, 'utf8'));
            const connectionOptions = {
                wallet, identity: 'Org1 Admin', discovery:
                    { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true }
            };
            await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, connectionOptions);
    
            // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
            const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
    
            const contract = network.getContract('qscc');
            const resultByte = await contract.evaluateTransaction(
                'GetBlockByNumber',
                'mychannel',
                '20'
            );
    
            const resultJson = BlockDecoder.decode(resultByte);
            logger.debug('queryBlock', resultJson);
    
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    void main();
```

I've tried to reinstall the "fabric-common" node module and BlockDecoder is present in the lib folder [image: fabric-common on the lib folder]

the package.json file code is this:

```
"engineStrict": true,
    "author": "Hyperledger",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "fabric-client": "^1.4.18",
        "fabric-common": "^2.2.9",
        "fabric-network": "~2.1.0",
        "sdk-fabric": "^1.0.8"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

While BlockDecoder is exported from the *fabric-common* package, it is currently missing from the TypeScript type definitions, as described by this bug report: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1722

Until a fix for that issue is published, you might need to play some tricks to get around the lack of type definition. Perhaps something like:

```
import * as common from 'fabric-common';
const BlockDecoder = (common as any).BlockDecoder;
```

I would recommend keeping the version of *fabric-common* and *fabric-network* packages you are using in step with each other. *fabric-network* uses *fabric-common* internally, so you are going to get a version of *fabric-common* in your `node_modules` directory regardless. You might as well avoid having multiple copies at different versions. Note that v2.2.x is currently the long-term support version, and v2.1.x of these packages are not recommended for use.